# Fast and cheap data aquisition

Tags: adc, microprocessor

I need to be able to analyse signals that are 10ns in length. It comes from a PMT (Photomultiplier tube) or an equivalent detector. We need to be able to trigger at a certain signal strength coming from the PMT. Microprocessors like the ATMega328P are way too slow to do this, but I also can't find any fast (100mhz+) a/d converters online. Any recommendations how I can tackle this problem with cheap and easy to use hardware?

Note: This is for a high-school project, the cost needs to be as low as possible.

EDIT: Please forgive my bad English.

Comment: _1)_ Your English is perfectly fine. _2)_ Do you just need to trigger off of a certain threshold, or _capture_ the waveform?

Comment: @Dzarda Just triggering. Blinking a led or buzzing a buzzer on a high enough signal is good.

Comment: One thing worth adding to your question is the gap between 10ns pulses. If there is enough spacing between pulses (or the actual count doesn't matter) you could probably use a Schmitt trigger from a sufficiently fast logic series to form a pulse extender circuit. You might not need a microcontroller at all unless there's another reason you need one.

Comment: @PeterJ the gap is random but approximately 2 seconds

Comment: Can't you change the pulse length using the final resistor? ATmega328 requires a pulse that is at least one clock (1/16M=65 ns) to be detected. Check atmega328p datasheet, "external clock source"

Answer (score 1):

When you need to trigger off of a fast signal, you don't need an ADC. You can just as easily use an *Analog Comparator*. Your ATMega already has one and I believe it will be fast enough. I believe the 328P doesn't have an internal reference, so you may have to provide one (could be just a voltage divider).

Then you can have an interrupt fired when you cross the threshold voltage, and you're set.

Comment: Will this be good enough: http://www.instructables.com/id/Girino-Fast-Arduino-Oscilloscope/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: @rhbvkleef This is way too complicated for your use I think. But you can use certain things...

Answer (score 0):

You could build a *monoflop*. The fast signal triggers the monoflop, which creates a pulse of a specified length. You can then easily analyse the monoflop output. If you only need to blink a LED (as you suggested in a comment), you could just place a switch at the monoflop output and switch on the LED with that.

One possibility would be to use a (LMC) 555 chip in monostable configuration. As @Brian Drummond remarked, I cannot guarantee that the 555 is fast enough and couldn't find according specs. It would maybe be safer to build a monoflop circuit from scratch or even better: use a monoflop chip with according specs (e.g. TI SN74AHC123)

Comment: Can a 555 even detect a 10ns pulse?

Comment: I couldn't find any corresponding entry in the datasheets. But at least the CMOS versions should easily be capable of that, or do you think not?

Comment: LMC55 datasheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf "Trigger propagation delay : typical : 100ns" - it's a fairly safe assumption it won't notice a pulse 10% of that. 74AHC123 would be a better bet. http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/15199/PHILIPS/74AHC123.html page 12 : Trigger pulse width : 5 ns

Answer (score 0):

I made a nice little PMT pulse amp from an AD8001 And then sent the signal into a nice fast comparator (LT1016).. With a pot setting the trigger level.  Do you have a 'scope that can see the PMT pulses?  Maybe you can just use the comparator.. if your signals are big enough.

Comment: I have a 20 mhz scope, not fast enough, I suppose I could use one at the university

Comment: @rhbvkleef, Well 20 MHz is better than nothing.. you might still see some pulses (stretched out some.)  Can you turn up the PMT voltage such that you get bigger pulses?  (Just reading some other comments... if your count rate is only 1 per second or so aren't you going to mostly be seeing dark counts?  What are you trying to do?  (I could suggest a quick cheap single photon detector... but it has terrible efficiency.)

Comment: We are trying to make a cheap and simple scintillator for high schools

Comment: Fun!  Are you going to try and "catch" some muons?  It's hard to get a good pmt and power supply for less than $1k.

Comment: Yes, I know, That is why we are trying to save on an expensive scope.

Comment: The 20 MHz 'scope should be enough to see the pulses.  (is it analog or digital?)  Beyond that with the pmt, a comparator and a counter you could look at the count rate as a function of the threshold voltage set by the comparator... that's actually more useful than looking at the pulses themselves.  Do you have the pmt?

Comment: my scope unfortunately is digital (usb scope)